# Cannot modify RIP register with Buffer Overflow

Tags: assembly, x86-64, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to overflow the buffer which is size of 32 ( buffer[32] ). Whenever I try to control 'rip' register there is a 'a' character overthere. For Example:

When I type 32xA + 8xB + 3xC (AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBCCC) I get the following output:
[image: Output1]

Moreover, when I type 32xA + 8xB + 5xC (AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBCCCCC) I get the following output:
[image: Output2]

If I add one C to that, the address changes completely. Both these outputs there is a 'a' character before the 'C's (43's).

How can I get rid of that 'a' in order to control rip?

Edit: When I used ^D to terminate the input, it worked and there was no 'a' in the address.

Comment: I assume you're typing input that is being placed in  the buffer. The 0x0a is the newline that you type at the end of the input.

Comment: If you can modify the test program, you can change it to replace the trailing newline with a null character.  If you are using a Unix-type system, you can use ^D to terminate the input line instead of Enter.

Comment: Do not post pictures of text please.  Instead, post the text as text.

Comment: `echo -en` is also used for such cases